# How to save pytorch models to Google drive from Kaggle notebook?

Tags: deep-learning, google-drive-api, kaggle, resuming-training

Every time when I finish training a model in Kaggle notebook, I need to download it to my PC first, then upload it to a Kaggle Dataset or my Google Drive for next training. I find this process tiring.

So are there any methods by which I can directly save my model to my Google Drive or something which will not be eliminated even when the program collapses? (Like in Google Notebook, we can mount at Google Drive and save our models in it during running.)