# Kaggle and saving/continuing train progress

Tags: google-drive-api, kaggle

This has been asked again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002803/how-to-save-pytorch-models-to-google-drive-from-kaggle-notebook), but there was no answer.
I am training a model for many many epochs. When I save the model using torch.save it goes to kaggle/working, which is deleted when the session ends, so I have to manually download the files. I want to train my model overnight withougt having the fear of losing my progress. Is there a way to connect it to my google drive like google collab?

Also, when I want to continue training, where should I upload the state_dict files? I guess making a new "dataset" to upload the files is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

To upload the state_dict files, a good approach is to select "file" from the menu bar at the top left area in Kaggle notebook, select "upload data". You can upload you dataset, better still compress the file(s) as zip, kaggle will unzip it.

On kaggle notebook, on the right panel there's an option for "persistence" select "Variables and Files". This will keep your file and variables saved.

To access your Google drive you need to "pip install PyDrive2". PyDrive2 is the forked maintained library of PyDrive

You could access this link for more instruction [https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/upload-files-to-google-drive-using-python][1]